# Soma de valores tendo em conta 3 campos da tabela

Tags: mysql, sql

Tenho a seguinte tabela `quotations` que serve para ir buscar os totais de vários orçamentos. E cada orçamento tem uma peça (`part_id`) que pode ter várias fazes:

```
+---------+-------------+----------+-----------------+
| part_id | alternative | revision | totals          |
+---------+-------------+----------+-----------------+
| 1       | 1           | 0        | 252.22          |
| 2       | 0           | 0        | 452             |
| 1       | 1           | 1        | 270             |
| 1       | 2           | 2        | 250             |
| 1       | 2           | 3        | 250             |
+---------+-------------+----------------------------+
```

Na tabela, quero fazer a soma de todos os totais, mas tendo em conta as seguintes regras:
- a part_id e alterantive é como se fosse um orçamento distinto
- Se houver mais que uma revisão (`revision`), vou buscar o total da ultima revisão.

Ou seja, inicialmente preciso de ficar com o seguinte:

```
+---------+-------------+----------+-----------------+
| part_id | alternative | revision | totals          |
+---------+-------------+----------+-----------------+
| 2       | 0           | 0        | 452             |
| 1       | 1           | 1        | 270             |
| 1       | 2           | 3        | 250             |
+---------+-------------+----------------------------+
```

Ou seja, no fim de ir buscar a ultima revisão para cada alternativa, quero somar o total final, que seria 972.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fiz primeiro o agrupamento para selecionar somente a maior revisão e depois a soma destes registros:

```
select sum(totals) 
from quotations 
where (part_id, alternative, revision) in 
      (select part_id, alternative, max(revision) from quotations group by part_id, alternative)
```

Comment: muito obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

Olá, tente isso:

```
SELECT part_id, alternative, revision, totals
FROM (
SELECT tb1.part_id, tb1.alternative, tb1.revision, tb1.totals,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY tb1.part_id ORDER BY tb1.revision DESC) AS RowNo
FROM orcamento tb1
) x
WHERE x.RowNo = 1
```

Espero ter ajudado.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: penso que terá algum erro, no OVER

Comment: Qual erro foi gerado?

Comment: Syntax error: Missing 'closing parenthesis'

Comment: Não é sua versão do sql server? acabei de editar a publicação com um print da mesma consulta sendo executada

Comment: colocou os mesmos dados? porque segundo o seu resultado ainda falta uma row

Comment: Basta alterar o filtro do where